# Set selected value on Html.DropdownListFor from mode asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I can't set a selected value in Dropdown based on my selected system. I tried other solutions that I saw, but still can't resolve my issue.

Here's my code.

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
public class IssuesModel
{
  public int ISSUE_ID {get; set;}
  public string SYSTEMNAME {get; set;}
  public string ISSUE_DESC {get; set;}
  .......
}

[Serializable]
public class IssueDetailViewModel
{
  public IssuesModel Issue {get; set}
  public ICollection<SystemSummaryViewModel> Systems {get; set;} = new List<SystemSummaryViewModel>();
  public SelectedSystemModel SelectedSystem {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class SystemSummaryViewModel
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string SYSTEMNAME {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class SelectedSystemModel
{
  public string SYSTEMNAME {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditIssue(int id = 0)
{
  var selectedIssue = db.TBL_ISSUES
     .Where(x => x.ISSUE_ID == id)
     .Select(x => new IssueModel
     {
       ISSUE_DESC = x.ISSUE_DESC,
       SYSTEMNAME = x.SYSTEMNAME
       ......
     }).FirstOrDefault();

  var systems = db.LIB_SYSTEMS
    .Where(x => x.ENABLED == "Y")
    .Select(x => new SystemSummaryViewModel
     {
       ID = x.ID,
       SYSTEMNAME = x.SYSTEMNAME
     }).ToList();

  var selectedSystem = db.TBL_ISSUES
    .Where(x = x.ISSUE_ID == id)
    .Select(x => new SelectedSystemModel
    {
      SYSTEMNAME = x.SYSTEMNAME
    }).FirstOrDefault();

  var model = new IssueDetailViewModel
  {
    Issue = selectedIssue,
    Systems = systems,
    SelectedSystem = selectedSystem
  }
};
return View(model);
```

**View**

```
@model ProjectName.Models.IssueDetailViewModle
@{
  Layout = null;
}
....
<div class="form-group">
  @{
     var systemList = new List<SelectedListItem>();
     foreach(var item in Model.Systems)
     {
       systemList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.SYSTEMNAME, Value = item.SYSTEMNAME}); //this is my current in populating dropdown values
     }
  }

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSystem.SYSTEMNAME, systemList, new { @class="control-label"})
//also tried below but no luck
@*
   Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSystem.SYSTEMNAME, new SelectList(Model.Systems, "SYSTEMNAME", "SYSTEMNAME", Model.SelectedSystem), "Select System", new { @class ="form-control"}
*@
</div>
```

I'm only getting the dropdown list but there is no default selected item.
Hope you can help me with this. Thank you so much and have a good day ahead

Answer (score 0):

@Html.DropDownListFor is very tricky about selected item, try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSystem.SYSTEMNAME, 
new SelectList(Model.Systems, "SYSTEMNAME", "SYSTEMNAME", 
Model.SelectedSystem.SYSTEMNAME), "Select System", new { @class ="form-control"}
```

so I prefer asp.net  select

```
@{
     var systemList = Model.Systems.Select(item=> new SelectListItem 
     { Text = item.SYSTEMNAME, 
       Value = item.SYSTEMNAME
      }).ToList();; 
}

......

<select class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedSystem.SYSTEMNAME" asp-items="@systemList"></select>
```